# How to select functions called inside nested loops before getting into loops?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

As shown in the following code, one of several atomic routines is called in the function `messagePassing`.
Which one to use is determined before diving into the nested loops.
In the current implementation, several `while` loops are used for sake of runtime performance.
I want to avoid repeating myself (repeating the shared operations in the nested loops) for sake of readability and maintainability, and achieve something like `messagePassingCleanButSlower`.

Is there a approach which does not sacrifice runtime performance?

I need to deal with two scenarios.

1. In the first one, the atomic routines are small and only involve 3 plus/minus operations, thus I guess they will be inlined.
2. In the second one, the atomic routines are big (about 200 lines) and hence unlikely to be inlined.

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<typename Uint, typename Real>
class Graph {
public:
  void messagePassing(Uint nit, Uint type);
  void messagePassingCleanButSlower(Uint nit, Uint type);

private:
  struct Vertex {}; // Details are hidden since they are distracting.
  std::vector< Vertex > vertices;

  void atomicMessagePassingType1(Vertex &v);
  void atomicMessagePassingType2(Vertex &v);
  void atomicMessagePassingType3(Vertex &v);
  // ...
  // may have other types
};

template<typename Uint, typename Real>
void
Graph<Uint, Real>::
messagePassing(Uint nit, Uint type)
{
  Uint count = 0;   // round counter
  if (type == 1) {
    while (count < nit) {
      ++count;
      // many operations
      for (auto &v : vertices) {
        // many other operations
        atomicMessagePassingType1(v);
      }
    }
  }
  else if (type == 2) {
    while (count < nit) {
      ++count;
      // many operations
      for (auto &v : vertices) {
        // many other operations
        atomicMessagePassingType2(v);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    while (count < nit) {
      ++count;
      // many operations
      for (auto &v : vertices) {
        // many other operations
        atomicMessagePassingType3(v);
      }
    }
  }
}

template<typename Uint, typename Real>
void
Graph<Uint, Real>::
messagePassingCleanButSlower(Uint nit, Uint type)
{
  Uint count = 0;   // round counter
  while (count < nit) {
    ++count;
    // many operations
    for (auto &v : vertices) {
      // many other operations
      if (type == 1) {
        atomicMessagePassingType1(v);
      }
      else if (type == 2) {
        atomicMessagePassingType2(v);
      }
      else {
        atomicMessagePassingType3(v);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, when I tried you code, I needed to put in an actual definition for `Vertex` - did I miss something?

Comment: @uneven_mark I am sorry that only declaration of `Vertex` is showed because it is actually coupled with other data members. Here the code is just for clarifying the question. The actual code conforms C++11.

Comment: Before C++17 `Vertex` would have needed to be complete (have definition) before the instantiation of `Graph` (because of `std::vector<Vertex> vertices;`). Since C++17 that is fine, but the type would need to be complete when the constructor or `messagePassingV1`/`messagePassingV2` (because of `for(auto& v : vertices)` are instantiated. No instantiation is shown here.

Comment: @uneven_mark For the big function, selection at runtime is acceptable so the pointer to member function is acceptable. But for the small function, I would like to have a approach which has similar performance to that of conditional compilation.

Comment: @Eli4ph No problem, but it would have made it easier to reproduce/test if you had given `Vertex` a trivial definition, i.e. `struct Vertex {};`.

Comment: Even with conditional compilation: Just use a dispatch function `void atomicMessagePassingType1or2(Vertex &v)` with a conditionally-compiled body.

Comment: @uneven_mark `messagePassingV2` is the intention and `messagePassingV1` is what I used to optimize the performance.

Comment: @Eli4ph If you simply want to avoid the multiple `if` tests, you could code two different `while` loops, selecting between them with just one `if (isType1)` test. Or is that too ugly?

Comment: @Adrian The compiler may very well be doing that optimization anyway, especially when the functions called are small and inlined. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ubObEh) is GCC (with `-O3`, but not with `-O2`) doing it, not even knowing what the called functions do.

Comment: @uneven_mark I am sorry that I did not put the question clearly and that the inclusion of the conditional compilation is incorrect for the purpose and is nothing but distracting. Now the question is extensively revised. I hope things become clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the benchmarks here:

1. http://quick-bench.com/rMsSb0Fg4I0WNFX8QbKugCe3hkc

For 1. I have setup a test scenario where the operations in `atomicMessagePassingTypeX` are really short (only an optimization barrier). I chose roughly `100` elements for `vertices` and `100` iterations of the outer `while`. These conditions are going to be different for your actual code, so whether my benchmark results apply to your case, you must verify by benchmarking your own code.

The four test cases are: Your two variants, the one with a function pointer mentioned in the other answers and one where the function pointer is called through a dispatching lambda, like this:

```
template<typename Uint, typename Real>
void
Graph<Uint, Real>::
messagePassingLambda(Uint nit, Uint type)
{
  using ftype = decltype(&Graph::atomicMessagePassingType1);
  auto lambda = [&](ftype what_to_call) {
    Uint count = 0;   // round counter
    while (count < nit) {
      ++count;
      // many operations
      for (auto &v : vertices) {
        // many other operations
        (this->*what_to_call)(v);
      }
    }
  };
  if(type == 1) lambda(&Graph::atomicMessagePassingType1);
  else if(type == 2) lambda(&Graph::atomicMessagePassingType2);
  else lambda(&Graph::atomicMessagePassingType3);
}
```

Try all combinations of GCC 9.1/Clang 8.0 and O2/O3. You will see that at O3 both compilers give roughly the same performance for your "slow" variant, in the case of GCC, it is actually the best. The compiler does hoist the `if`/`else` statements out of at least the inner loops and then, for some reason that is not completely clear to me, GCC does reorder the instructions in the inner loop differently than it does for the first variant, resulting in it being even a slightly bit faster.

The function pointer variant is consistently slowest.

The lambda variant is effectively equal to your first variant in performance. I guess it is clear why they are essentially the same if the the lambda is inlined.

If it is not inlined, then there might be a significant performance penalty due to the indirect call of `what_to_call`. This can be avoided by forcing a different type with appropriate direct call at each call site of `lambda`:

With C++14 or later you can make a generic lambda:

```
 auto lambda = [&](auto what_to_call) {
```

adjust the call form `(this->*what_to_call)(v);` to `what_to_call();` and call it with another lambda:

```
lambda([&](){ atomicMessagePassingType1(v); });
```

which will force the compiler to instantiate one function per dispatch and that should remove any potential indirect calls.

With C++11 you cannot make a generic lambda or variable template and so you would need to write an actual function template taking the secondary lambda as argument.

Comment: I am shocked by the benchmark. Then the answer boils down to "Don't do it yourself and let the optimized compiler." By the way, the approach using lambdas is also good for both readability/maintainability and performance. Thanks.

Comment: @Eli4ph Yes, here at high optimization level the compiler can be trusted to find the best codegen. There may be reasons why you would prefer O2 over O3. At O2 (at least in the case of gcc) optimizations such as this are not enabled, because they can increase the generated code size significantly. With the lambda method you really should make sure that you are passing the member function pointer as template argument, because the indirect calls in a non-inlined lambda may be very costly otherwise. I didn't write it out in C++11 conformant syntax, because that is going to look very messy.

Comment: @Eli4ph I made a stupid mistake. The variable template I showed does not in fact resolve the issue of potential indirect calls. I have now fixed this in a way that is also more generic (not limited to member function calls).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function pointer to make the decision before entering the loop, like so:

```
template<typename Uint, typename Real>
void
Graph<Uint, Real>::
messagePassingV2(Uint nit, bool isType1)
{
    void (Graph::* aMPT_Ptr)(Vertex &); // Thanks to @uneven_mark for the corerct
    if (isType1)
        aMPT_Ptr = &Graph<Uint, Real>::atomicMessagePassingType1;  // syntax here
    else
        aMPT_Ptr = &Graph<Uint, Real>::atomicMessagePassingType2;
    Uint count = 0;   // round counter
    while (count < nit) {
        ++count;
        for (auto& v : vertices) {
            (this->*aMPT_Ptr)(v); // Again, thanks to @uneven_mark for the syntax!
        }
    }
}
```

The one thing that remains as a potential issue is what happens if either of the functions 'assigned' to the pointer is inlined. I'm thinking that, as there is code taking the address of these functions, then the compiler will probably prevent any inlining.

Comment: @uneven_mark Thanks for the corrections! I've re-opened the answer but I feel the credit should go to you. Why don't you post the answer?

Comment: That's fine. While your solution does work now, I don't think it is the direction OP should take. To figure out what the correct direction is, I am waiting for them to answer my comment. A simple dispatching function would do it as well, but I suspect OP has a reason not to use that approach.

Comment: @uneven_mark Thanks to both of you. This solution (pointer to member functions) solves the second half of my question. But I also need a solution which will not prevent inlining, when the member functions are very small.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways.

1) Bool param.  This really just moves the if/else into the function... but that's a good thing when you use the function[s] in multiple places, and a bad thing if you're trying to move the test out of the loop.  OTOH, speculative execution should mitigate that.

2) Member function pointers.  Nasty syntax in the raw, but 'auto' can burry all that for us.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


class Foo
{
public:
  void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
  void baz() { std::cout << "baz\n"; }
};

void callOneABunch(Foo& foo, bool callBar)
{
    auto whichToCall = callBar ? &Foo::bar : &Foo::baz;
    // without the auto, this would be "void(Foo::*)()"
    // typedef void(Foo::*TypedefNameGoesHereWeirdRight)();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
      std::invoke(whichToCall, foo); // C++17
      (foo.*whichToCall)(); // ugly, several have recommended wrapping it in a macro
      Foo* foop = &foo;
      (foop->*whichToCall)(); // yep, still ugly
    }
}

int main() {
    Foo myFoo;
    callOneABunch(myFoo, true);
}
```

You can also take a swing at this with `std::function` or `std::bind`, but after arguing with `fuction` for a bit, I fell back on the bare syntax.

Comment: Mostly this if from information I found at https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Thanks, the pointers to members are acceptable to switch between two big functions. So it solves a half of my problem. Unfortunately, the another half is about switching between two small functions without much overhead since they will be called many times.